# jquery dialog box

Tags: php, jquery, dialog

i'm working on a login form. 
here's the code

```
<?php 
   require_once('../../SfHelper.php'); 
   $sfHelper = new SfHelper();
   echo $sfHelper->load_css('ui-lightness/login');
?>


<div name="form_Login" class="form_Login">
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo 
      $sfHelper->base_url().'forms/jobseeker/'; ?>process_Login.php" >
<table width="296" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3">LOGIN JOB SEEKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td width="110">Username</td>
       <td width="18">:</td>
       <td width="209"><input type="text" name="txtUsername" 
            id="txtUsername" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Password</td>
       <td>:</td>
       <td><input type="password" name="txtPassword" id="txtPassword" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3">

   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3"><div align="center">
          <input type="submit" name="Login" id="Login" value="Login" />
          </div></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</div>


<?php
if(isset($_GET['err']))
{
   if($_GET['err'] == "Sorry, We Cannot found your Username")
   {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
               alert("Sorry, We Cannot found your Username"); </script>';

   }
   else if($_GET['err'] == "Invalid Username or Password")
   {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
                     alert("Invalid Username or Password");</script>';
   }
}
?>
```

the thing is I need to display the error message using jquery modal dialog box rather than use alert. I have no clue whatsoever about using jquery nor that i have mastered php or javascript. Can anyone show me how its done?

i have reworked my codes and added

```
if(isset($_GET['err']))
{
     if($_GET['err'] == "Sorry, We Cannot found your Username")
     {
        echo '<script type="application/javascript">
           $("#Login").click(function() {
              $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                 modal: true,
                 buttons: {
                    Ok: function() {
                       $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                 }
              });
           });
       </script>';
     }
     else if($_GET['err'] == "Invalid Username or Password")
     {
         echo '<script type="application/javascript">
            $("#Login").click(function() {
                 "#dialog-message2" ).dialog({
                     modal: true,
                     buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                           $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                     }
                 });
            });
        </script>';
    }
}
```

here's the div that want to show if login failed

```
   <div id="dialog-message" style="display:none" >
    <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" 
                style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Sorry, We Cannot found your Username
    </p>
   </div>

  <div id="dialog-message2" style="display:none" >
    <p>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" 
                 style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
    Invalid Username or Password
    </p>
  </div>
```

it seems not working. can anyone show me where i did wrong?

Comment: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Comment: You should go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'ready',before the page will fully loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Code using $ as usual goes here.
  //The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.
});

  echo '<script type="application/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                     $("#Login").click(function() {
                        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                              modal: true,
                              buttons: {
                              Ok: function() {
                               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                              }
                             }
                         });
                       });
                       });
         </script>';
```